# Remote Desktop Service disabled but event log entries are being generated

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-desktop, event-log

The service `Remote Desktop Services`, and all other `Remote Desktop XXX` services, are disabled in my list of services. However, every time I start the computer, the following event is generated (usually twice, but occasionally only once):

```
Event ID = 17
Level = Error
Channel = Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational
Provider = Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager
Description = Remote Desktop Service start failed. The relevant status code was 0x80070422.
```

Why are these event log entries being generated and how do I stop them? Running Windows 8.1.

Comment: Presumably you have another service trying to start that is dependent on RDS and so cannot start as you have RDS disabled.

Comment: Good thought, but when I checked the `The following system components depend on this service` section for each `Remote Desktop XXX` service, none had anything listed (apart from other `Remote Desktop XXX` services). My system lists these three services `Remote Desktop Configuration`, `Remote Desktop Services` and `Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector`.